# TapGesture won't fire when adjusted inside a layout Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So basically I have an annoying thing when I'm trying to adjust my frame inside an `AbsoluteLayout` such:

```
<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="4">
<Frame CornerRadius="20" 
    Padding="0"  
    BorderColor="#9f6b34"  
    Background="Transparent">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="fourthButton_Clicked"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
         <Label Text="Classic and traditional" 
                Padding="35" 
                FontSize="40"
                FontFamily="font2" 
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                TextColor="#211717">
          </Label>
     </Frame>
```

When the code is like this it's fine but when I try to adjust the frames' position with `.LayoutBounds` it just won't click. I've tried changing it to a `StackLayout` and click event fires sometimes in various different positions inside the frame. I've put `ImageButton`, regular button and also tried using my label's `GestureRecognizer` but it just won't click when I made adjustments.
[here is a gif of the situtation. the top frame isn't adjusted the bottom one is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IIXE.gif)

Comment: AbsoluteLayout can overlap views and it blocks the tap gestures also. I would suggest to go with the Grid. If you want to keep the AbsolutLayout, you should carefully use the z value which is the position of the view's anchor. Default value should be 0 and this caused the overlapping.

Comment: @IlnamJeong I've tried putting it in the grid , when I use something like <Frame Grid.Row="0"/> my gesture overlaps again but after removing it it works. And the z value means the width right ?

Comment: @Cfun tried them both didn't work

Comment: Try to build a small page for replicating and post the code.

Comment: @Shaw well when I do that it works but in my main project its more complicated. I have a horizontal scrollview and have a big grid in it. That grid has 5 coloumns which I use them as different pages for scrolling between them. And this page is one of them.

Comment: You mean <Frame Grid.Row="0"/> works for some empty columns inside a scrollview? I'm not a fan of AbsoluteLayout anyway, when you use Grid, try to add one column a time until broken.

Comment: @hekean1339 check this out. You should adjust anchor values (x, y) to avoid the overlapping problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132510/why-tap-gesture-recognizer-wont-work-in-absolute-layout

Answer (score 0):

> When the code is like this it's fine but when I try to adjust the frames' position with .LayoutBounds it just won't click.

I try your code, and it works fine, having no problem, please take a look the following code:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <AbsoluteLayout>
                <Frame
                    Padding="0"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 10, 300, 200"
                    BorderColor="#9f6b34"
                    CornerRadius="20">
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="fourthButton_Clicked" />
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label
                        Padding="35"
                        FontFamily="font2"
                        FontSize="40"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="Classic and traditional"
                        TextColor="#211717" />
                </Frame>
            </AbsoluteLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <Frame
                    Padding="0"
                    BorderColor="#9f6b34"
                    CornerRadius="20">
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="fourthButton_Clicked" />
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label
                        Padding="35"
                        FontFamily="font2"
                        FontSize="40"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="Classic and traditional"
                        TextColor="#211717" />
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

I put Frame in AbsoluteLayout and also use **AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds** to adjust Frame poaition, I also put frame in StackLayout, it also works fine.

Comment: the issue was happening probably because I had many layouts in the same page something was overlapping and I couldn't know which or where. Anyway I ditched the AbsoluteLayout and used Grid and somehow it worked. I tried the same thing yesterday but it didn't work but now it does. Thanks anyway

Comment: @hekean1339 If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, it may help others, thanks.

Comment: I've tried your code but like I said my main project was a mess and it was overlapping with something so it didn't work. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @hekean1339 If you still have some problem, please provide your entire sample and providing some screenshots to describe your problem.

Comment: In my first comment I've already said that I've switched to Grid and its working.